# Text Input focus anomaly in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I am trying out this rather simple code. It is supposed to shift the focus to the neighboring text input whenever there is `mouseup` on the first one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">   
    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".foo").mouseup(function() {
          $(".boo").focus();
        });
      });   
    </script>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <input type='text' class='foo' />
    <input type='text' class='boo' />
  </body>    
</html>
```

In all browsers except `IE9` (I didn't dare test it in `IE8` or below!), it works fine for both left button and right button (for right button `mouseup`, the context menu still pops up on the first input even though the focus shifts to the 2nd one). However, in `IE9`, the focus still remains on the first text input (the context menu also popping up there).

Is there any way to fix it so that the focus shifts to the 2nd one?

Comment: Can you try doing this in pure JS just to see if it works? So document.getElementById(element).focus();

Comment: Lemme try. Give me two minutes...

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work, as expected..:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.select() in ie should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/n4hGC/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.foo').mouseup(function() {
    $('.boo').focus();
  });
  $('.foo').contextmenu(function() {
      $('.boo').select();
      return false;
  });
});
```

Have also handled the context menu by returning false.
Hope helps!

Comment: Well, that works. Is there a jQuery equivalent of `contextmenu` event?

Comment: Dude, another question, is it supported in IE8 as well?

Comment: Quickly mocked up a non jquery version and ran in ie7,8 standards modes (F12) and worked, so should be fine, you should check though

Comment: Can you tell me whether the jQuery versions works as well? I don't have an IE8 for testing..:(

Comment: F12 on IE9 brings up console, click on browser mode, change to IE8 and then change document mode and change to IE8

Comment: Cool. Will do that..Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can you try one of these alternatives? They have worked for me in IE8 in the past and they might work for you.

Alternative 1: Blur then Focus

```
$(".foo").mouseup(function(){
    $(".boo").blur();  
    $(".boo").focus();
});
```

Alternative 2: Using setTimeout

```
$(".foo").mouseup(function(){ 
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".boo").focus();
    }, 100);  
});
```